# VB.NET Removing first line of a textbox

Tags: vb.net, textbox

How can i remove the first line of a textbox on a button press?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this :

```
  Dim b As String() = Split(TextBox1.Text, vbNewLine)

  TextBox1.Text = String.Join(vbNewLine, b, 1, b.Length - 1)
```

See [String.Join](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa904289%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) for reference .

Answer (score 1):

fairly easy:

```
Private Sub bttnFirstLine_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles bttnFirstLine.Click
        txtBox.Text = txtBox.Text.Substring(txtBox.Text.IndexOf(vbCrLf))
end sub
```

or

```
Private Sub bttnFirstLine_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles bttnFirstLine.Click
            dim myString = txtBox.text
            txtBox.Text = myString.Substring(myString.IndexOf(vbCrLf))
    end sub
```

Comment: Hi thanks it worked How can i make it also press the delete button? cause it deletes it but leaves the line there i want it to make the line also delete so it shifts up the next one

Comment: Change that to `txtBox.Text = myString.Substring(myString.IndexOf(vbCrLf)) + 2`  You have to skip over the LF and CR characters.

Comment: @Hand-E-Food Conversion from string "joe" to type 'Double' is not valid.

is my code
                Dim myString = gathered.TextBox1.Text
                gathered.TextBox1.Text = myString.Substring(myString.IndexOf(vbCrLf)) + 2

Comment: Try `Dim myString As String = ...`. Always declare the type of your variables.

Comment: @Hand-E-Food, only if he's not using option infer on,which he should